# How to correctly access a specific Weierstrass p-function in PARI?

Tags: math-software, elliptic-functions

I want to write a script for PARI containing the Weierstrass p-function. I know that the right command is "ellwp(lattice,value,flag)". But if I need to work with the p-function for the same lattice multiple times and I set up a variable for it (p = ellwp([1,I]), how can I evaluate it afterwards?

Intuitively I try "p(0.2 * I)", but I always get the error message "*** not a function in function call".

I guess I could avoid this issue if I only set up a variable for the lattice and always call the ellwp function, but I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: `p(z) = ellwp([1,I],z)`. Also the [GIT](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/windows/snapshots/) binary versions contain all the packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function $\;\texttt{p = z->ellwp[1, I], z)}\;$ with a given lattice $\;\texttt{[1, I]}\;$and then, for example, you do $\;\texttt{p(0.2*I)}\;$ any time later using the given lattice.